# Put multiple values of different variables in one column SAS

Tags: sas, multiple-columns

I have a dataset similar to this (Se is variable Serious):

Se  D  L  C  Di H O

N

N

N

Y   N  Y  N  N  N N

N

N

N

Y   N  Y  N  Y N N

variables *Death (D), Life_Threat (L), Congenital_anom (C), Disability (Di), Hospitalizaion (H) and Other (O)* have to match a value from 1 (for variable *Death*) to 6 (for variable*Other*) and I have to record these values in a new variable that in the case for example of the last line where I have two 'Y' takes into account both values in this way 2,4. How can I do it? (I have lines where all 6 variables are Y).

Thanks in advance

I don’t know how to set the new variable so that it considers all the 6 variables for which I have Y

Comment: Please show your expected output and add anything you've tried to solve this so far.

Comment: As output is quite free, for now I have no precise guidelines on how it should be, as for the resolution I have an idea but I don't know how to express it by SAS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function catx to combine values to one string:

Generating your sample data:

```
data have;
input Se $1. D $1. L $1. C $1. Di $1. H $1. O $1.;
datalines;
N
N
N
YNYNNNN
N
N
N
YNYNYNN
YYYYYYY
run;
```

Here, an array is defined that consists of the six input variables and the function catx is used. In "synthesis" you will find the lists of Y-values in the form "2" or "2,4", respectively, or "1,2,3,4,5,6" in the last example.

```
data want (drop=i);
set have;
length synthesis $12;
array yn {6} D L C Di H O;
do i=1 to 6;
  if yn{i}="Y" then synthesis=catx(',',synthesis,put(i,$1.));
end;
run;
```